# Merging rows based on id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has multiple rows such as:

```
ID    Diagnosis      Procedure
1     2              A
1     4              B
```

I would like to make it so the output is:

```
ID    DiagnosisAndProcedures
1     2, A, 4, B
```

I was wondering, what is the most efficient way to achieve this.  Thanks for the help!!

```
SELECT PatientID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(DiagnosisCodeType, ', ', Procedures) SEPARATOR ', ') AS DiagnosisAndProcedures
FROM (SELECT PatientID, DiagnosisCodeType, GROUP_CONCAT(ProcedureID SEPARATOR ', ') AS Procedures
      FROM (SELECT revenue.HCPCCode, revenue.HCPCCodeCount, patient.*, icd9.DiagnosisCodeType, procedures.ProcedureID, procedures.ProcedureDate, claims.ClaimThroughDate, icd9.ICDAccessCode
FROM database.revenue revenue
RIGHT OUTER JOIN database.patient patient
    ON revenue.ClaimID = patient.ClaimID
JOIN database.diagnosisicd9 icd9
    ON revenue.ClaimID = icd9.ClaimID
JOIN database.claims claims
    ON revenue.ClaimID = claims.ClaimID
JOIN database.procedures procedures
    ON revenue.ClaimID = procedures.ClaimID
AND revenue.HCPCCode IN (659, 698, 5116, 5118, 5122, 5123, 5127, 12164, 12171, 16976, 17283) 
      GROUP BY PatientID, DiagnosisCodeType) AS subquery
GROUP BY PatientID
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Diagnosis, ', ', Procedure) SEPARATOR ', ') AS DiagnosisAndProcedures
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

For the table in your comment, you first use a subquery to concatenate all the procedures for the same ID and Diagnosis, then use the outer query to concatenate all the Diagnosis and Procedures for the same ID.

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Diagnosis, ', ', Procedures) SEPARATOR ', ') AS DiagnosisAndProcedures
FROM (SELECT ID, Diagnosis, GROUP_CONCAT(Procedure SEPARATOR ', ') AS Procedures
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY ID, Diagnosis) AS subquery
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks! What if it was a table like:
ID    Diagnosis      Procedure
1     2                    A
1     4                    B
1     4                    C 

And i wanted it to look like:
ID    DiagnosisAndProcedures
1     2, A, 4, B, C

Thanks for the help again!

Comment: You'll need to use a subquery. The inner query uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate all the procedures with the same ID+Diagnosis. The outer query then works like my query.

Comment: What should i use to replace mytable?  Sorry I am very new to sql.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i do not know what table i should use instead of my table.  My code doesnt seem to give me a name for the table that is produces.

Comment: All tables in a MySQL database have names.

Comment: You give the table a name when you make it with `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: How are you doing anything in SQL if you don't know the table name?

Comment: the table that i am using was mined from a big database that I have.  I didnt have to create one i dont think.

Comment: You mean it's the output of a query? Just make it another subquery: `FROM (SELECT ID, Diagnosis, Procedure FROM bigdatabase ...)`

Comment: You can always replace a table name in `FROM` or `JOIN` with a subquery that generates the data.

Comment: i added a SELECT ID, Diagnosis, Procedure instead of the myTable and it didnt seem to work.

Comment: You have to put the entire query that you used to get the data that you displayed in the question. I think you need to go back to the books and learn SQL, I'm not going to try to spoon feed this whole thing.[

Comment: And don't forget the parentheses around the subquery.

Comment: thanks for the help!  I tried to do what you told me to do but for some reaso i get the error: "no database selected."  I appreciate your help very much, i am just very new to sql, sorry!  I posted the code i used above